# Create Sibling ItemViews with a CollectionView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone.marionette application that is using a CollectionView to output the following:

- div#main .widget

  - div.head
  - div.body

Here are the 2 sibling ItemViews:

```
var LogLocationBodyView = App.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    attributes: {class: "body"},
    template: "#log-location-body-template"
});

var LogLocationHeadView = App.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    attributes: {class: "head"},
    template: "#log-location-head-template" 
});
```

And here is the CollectionView:

```
var LogLocationsView = App.CollectionView.extend({
    template: "#log-locations-template",
    attributes: {id: "main", class: "widget"},
    itemView: LogLocationHeadView
});
```

I can obviously get LogLocationHeadView to render but I'm looking for the best approach to inserAfter() LogLocationBodyView, so that the 2 ItemViews are siblings.

What is the best way to pull this off? I've tried a number of different approaches. First I tried to use the onRender() of my ItemView, but quickly realized I could only append to the markup in the view. I really need to insertAfter() and parent is unavailable since within onRender we are still pre-DOM insertion.

```
var LogLocationHeadView = App.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    attributes: {class: "head"},
    template: "#log-location-head-template",
    onRender: function() {

        // create a new piece of html from a different template
        var view = new LogLocationBodyView({
            model: this.model
        });

        view.render();

        $(this.el).append(view.el);

        var c = $(this.el).children();
            console.log(c); // true

        var p = $(this.el).parents();
            console.log(p); //undefined

    }
```

I also understand I can override the appendHTML() and renderItem() methods within CollectionViews, but I need to still be able to append(). So I would need to be able to pass a renderType.

What I really would like to do is pass an array of ItemViews along with a renderType to renderItem. Then, renderItems could fork within appendHTML().

```
var LogLocationsView = App.CollectionView.extend({
    template: "#log-locations-template",
    attributes: {id: "main", class: "widget"},
    itemViews: [{view: LogLocationHeadView, renderType: append}, {view: LogLocationBodyView, renderType: insertAfter}]
});
```

Before I try to do that, Id like to see if I am completely off base here. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered awhile back starting here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/36.
 and here: 
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/35

Now it is a full feature :

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleanest way to do that would be to have parent view of header and body views append both these views in its `render` method rather then having to rely on `insertAfter`. If you'd like to handle it from view which haven't been inserted yet but will be at the end of current browser event loop you can defer inserting the views to the next loop using either the underscore `defer` method or the setTimeout(fn, 1) method.

and btw. you don't need to specify the tagName if it is a `div` as div is a default value for tagName.